# Why Spring throws exceptions when No default constructor is found

Tags: java, spring

A simple test Shopping Application where i have two classes Clothing and Offers.
Now on calling *formalshirt* bean, it throws the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'DiwaliOffer' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [Offers]: No default constructor found; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Offers.<init>()
```

Now if i comment the Offers constructor, the app runs successfully. My query is Why does Spring looks for default constructor only when there is another constructor?

**Clothing Class**

```
public class Clothing {
    private int price;
    private List<Offers> offer;

    public void setOffer(List<Offers> offer) {
        this.offer = offer;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

.

**Offers Class**

```
public class Offers {
    private int discount;
    private String promocode;

    public Offers(int val1, String val2)
    {
        this.discount=val1;
        this.promocode=val2;
    }

    //public Offers(){} /*Default Constructor added due to Spring Exception as in below */  
    /* Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class No default constructor found */
    /* Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.Shopping.Offers.<init>() */

    public void setDiscount(int discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public void setPromocode(String promocode) {
        this.promocode = promocode;
    }
}
```

**Spring.xml**

```
<bean id="formalshirt" class="com.test.Shopping.Clothing">
    <property name="price" value="800"></property>              
    <property name="offer">
        <list>
            <ref bean="DiwaliOffer" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="DiwaliOffer" class="com.test.Shopping.Offers">
    <property name="discount" value="10"></property>
    <property name="promocode" value="diwali"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your Spring XML configuration of `Offers` to:

```
<bean id="DiwaliOffer" class="com.test.Shopping.Offers">
    <constructor-arg value="10"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="diwali"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The way you have configured it, Spring first attempts to call the default constructor and then call the setters. But of course there is no default constructor, and there fore Spring reports the exception.

Another option if you are using Spring 3+ is to use Java Config, instead of XML config.
You would just have

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

   //add other beans

   @Bean
   public Offers DiwaliOffer() {
      return new Offers(10, diwali);
   }
}
```

In your case Java Config has the benefit that your configuration would not even compile if you didn't call the constructor, ie. it would fail early instead of fail late as with the XML configuration

Spring is extremely flexible with how it creates beans, but you need to declare how it will be done

Comment: yes, spring is calling the default constructor, but if i comment the public Offers(int val1, String val2) constructor then why isn't it still calling the default constructor ?

Comment: If you totally comment out the 2-arg constructor (and make sure no old code left around) then a default constructor will exist and Spring will able to call it. In Java when no constructor is present in the source code, then the compiler automatically generates a no-arg constructor

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you add `parametrize constructor`, you need to tell `spring` to intanitate by giving `constructor` argument...

The concept is straight forward:

in default constriuctor case you will simply create object like `new Test()`;

where as when you don't have default rather have parameterize constructor you have to create object like `new Test1("test")`;

```
Class Test{

}

Class Test1{
      Test1(String a){

}
}
```

Spring way will be:

```
<bean id="test1" class="Test1">

<constructor-arg value="Zara"/>
</bean
```

Please have look at [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You need to use constructor-args for your bean properties so that it picks the non-default constructor. Otherwise Spring creates the object first, and without any parameters, it must use the zero-arg constructor, then sets properties with setters.

To pass in constructor args, change property to constructor-arg like so:

```
<bean id="DiwaliOffer" class="com.test.Shopping.Offers">

    <constructor-arg index="0" value="10"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="diwali" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are any `constructor` available in the class then java compiler does not provide default constructor.

And we can see `com.test.Shopping.Clothing` can able to create instance and `com.test.Shopping.Offers` can't.

To create the instance you need to pass `constructor-arg` of `discount` and `promocode`.

```
<bean id="DiwaliOffer" class="com.test.Shopping.Offers">
    <constructor-arg value="10"></property>
    <constructor-arg value="diwali"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: i understand that class needs an instance but it didn't look for any instance when i had the offers class with no constructor defined

Comment: u see the same config, with below offers class worked

Comment: `public class Offers {
 private int discount;
 private String promocode; 

 public void setDiscount(int discount) {
  this.discount = discount;
 }

 public void setPromocode(String promocode) {
  this.promocode = promocode;
 }
}`

Comment: In that case you need to create default constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
<bean id="DiwaliOffer" class="com.test.Shopping.Offers" >
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="10" />
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Diwali"/>
</bean>
```

The constructor-arg element within the bean element is used to set the property value thru constructor injection. Since there is only one constructor in the User bean class, this code will work fine.